# How do I install Wine on Ubuntu 17.10 64-bit?

Tags: software-installation, wine

Running on Ubuntu Desktop 17.10, I tried to install `wine` but I always get the following error message:

```
root@abdrzj-VPCEH26EA:/etc/apt# apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Package wine is a virtual package provided by:

  winehq-devel 2.22.0~xenial
  wine-stable 2.0.2-2ubuntu1
  wine-development 2.18-1
You should explicitly select one to install.
E: Package 'wine' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Tried http://tipsonubuntu.com/2017/05/26/wine-2-9-released-install-ubuntu/?

Comment: As the message says run `sudo apt-get winehq-devel`, or `sudo apt-get wine-stable`, or `sudo apt-get wine-development`.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-devel : Depends: wine-devel-i386 (= 2.22.0~artful)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 3):

try:

`sudo apt-get install wine-stable`

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 2.0.3~artful)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: have a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

Answer (score -1):

Run command to install the key:

`wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key && sudo apt-key add Release.key`

Also add the Wine repository via command:

`sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/`

run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` to make sure 32 bit architecture is enabled

Lastly, run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --install-recommends wine-stable` to install wine-stable.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-devel : Depends: wine-devel-i386 (= 2.22.0~artful)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.